# Does the ground effect change with temperature changes?

Tags: aircraft-performance, ground-effect

The title is my question. Does the ground effect change as the temperature of the ground changes? In cold weather, a more cushion effect can be expected, and in hot weather vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is nothing in the physics of ground effect that depends on temperature.

On a hot day, you will have higher density altitude.  Your true approach speed will be greater (for the same equivalent airspeed).  You may perceive a difference in the way the landing feels because you are moving faster across the ground, but there is no difference in ground effect.

Also, on a hot day, thermals can form over dark areas of ground.  This convective activity can cause an aircraft on final to float.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume:

1. You are asking about the temperature of the air near the ground, not the temperature of the ground itself.
2. The ground effect is the pressure caused by compression of air between the wing and the ground.
3. The ambient pressure does not depend on the temperature and the ground effect is isentropic.

The temperature of the air near the ground has a quite small relationship to the ground effect.  The ground effect can be simplistically described with the isentropic compressibility, which is [inversely related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility#Relation_to_speed_of_sound) to the square of the speed of sound.  As temperature increases, [the speed of sound increases slightly.](https://www.nde-ed.org/Physics/Sound/tempandspeed.xhtml)  This would cause an increase in ground effect.  The difference would be too small to be relevant to pilots or aircraft designers.

If you accounted for turbulence and phase changes (such as water condensing) then you may see other differences due to deviation from the ideal gas law.  These may be slightly less tiny near the melting point of water.

Comment: So much wrong here.  Ground effect has nothing to do with compressibility -- isentropic or otherwise.

Ground effect can be observed with potential flow assumptions (inviscid, incompressible).  Potential flow of an aircraft has boundary conditions that die off far away.  The ground plane inserts a plane of symmetry.  This can be replaced by placing a mirror of the flow across the symmetry plane.

So, if the wing was a horseshoe vortex, in ground effect, it would be the same as a mirror pair of horseshoe vortices in free air.

Temperature does not appear in potential flow.

Comment: Wind tunnels do have climate control. Many closed circuit wind tunnels include coolers to keep the flows' temperature from constantly rising during long runs.  Some wind tunnels are sealed and pressurized. This way, they run at higher than ambient pressure, helping them to match a desired flight Reynolds number. The NTF - National Transonic Facility at NASA Langley is a pressure tunnel that injects liquid Nitrogen to cool the flow (and keep it cold).  It does this to try to simultaneously match Reynolds and Mach number.

Comment: Some wind tunnel models are heated - and observed with an IR camera.  The differences in surface temperature can reveal where the flow transitions from laminar to turbulent.  These instruments are only sensitive for a narrow range of temperatures - this kind of experiment will only work with a tunnel operating over a certain range of temps.

Comment: 1. Planes cannot fly in inviscid fluids.  2. Just because something can be observed under some assumptions does not mean the assumptions always apply when the thing is observed.  3.  You may be right about wind tunnels - I look forward to more answers to the other question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111659/would-an-airplane-flying-through-superfluid-helium-experience-lift-and-drag

Comment: @RobMcDonald 4. Potential flow does not occur in aviation.

Comment: All models are wrong, some models are useful.  Potential flow is _the_most_important_ theory for _understanding_ aerodynamics.  The Euler and Navier Stokes equations may be more accurate in certain conditions (but still have simplifications and assumptions), and can be solved numerically -- but they provide almost zero insight and understanding.  All aircraft are designed and understood using ideas of potential theory. In this case, the inviscid assumption is presumably the one you're taking issue with -- it is irrelevant to the ground effect conversation.

Comment: Your link about superfluid helium is irrelevant.

Comment: "All aircraft are designed and understood using ideas of potential theory."  Designed, maybe, but the claim they are "understood" without accounting for compression is wildly implausible.  I took the question to be about reality, not models.  It would be best answered with a very precise experiment.  I have no further interest in your opinions about potential flow.

Comment: Compressibility is insignificant below about Mach 0.6.  Even high performance supersonic aircraft land at about Mach 0.3.  I.e. all aircraft takeoff and land in the incompressible regime.  Before you discount the importance of potential flow to understanding aerodynamics, I suggest you learn something about it.

Comment: @RobMcDonald In my opinion, the question is about tiny differences.  You have criticized without providing any equations or data.  Here is an experiment that shows the obvious fact air is compressible:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC6Me1zfyCM

Comment: I never said air was not compressible.  I stated how ground effect is studied, modeled, and understood by aerodynamicists.  I.e. By treating the ground as a symmetry plane and replacing the body with a mirror body -- and that this is normally done with potential flow models.  I have also stated that aircraft land (i.e. when ground effect is important) at speeds where compressibility effects are generally ignored.  You have made claims that potential flow is not relevant.  Open almost any book on aerodynamics, you will find the majority of it discusses potential flow.

Comment: @RobMcDonald It seems obvious to me that books would discuss potential flow - that tells us nothing about the question asked here.  Likewise, the practices of aerodynamicists tell us nothing about the question asked here.  Aerodynamicists should not care about tiny changes in the properties of air.  Appeals to authority are not going to change my mind about anything.  Try very precise data, or perhaps equations that account for very small effects.

Comment: Aerodynamicists would certainly care if it mattered.  They would certainly care about anything that had to do with ground effect.  Ground effect can be entirely explained without effects of temperature -- you have made no case otherwise.

Comment: @RobMcDonald "Ground effect can be entirely explained without effects of temperature -- you have made no case otherwise."  That is because ground effect can be explained without effects of temperature.  In my opinion the question is about something that doesn't matter for aviation.